# Logical union of data from tables with diverging numbers and types of columns

Tags: sql, union

Consider a logical union (may not actually use the 'union' keyword) of the following three (or more) tables:

```
TableA: common_key int, 'TableA' as tname', taba_col1 string, taba_col2 int
TableB: common_key int, 'TableB' as tname',  tabb_col1 double, tabb_col2 double, tabb_col3 string
..
TableN: common_key int, 'TableN' as tname', tabn_col1 int, tabn_col2 date, tabn_col3 date
```

We want something along the lines of:

```
create table union_table as select * from TableA union select * from TableB .. union select * from TableN order by common_key, tname;
```

Then we can easily see all of the table data grouped by common_key by doing the following:

```
select * from union_table
```

What would be a reasonable way to obtain a union of all these tables? Note: we do NOT want to do a join here: we want all rows to be separate.

Comment: the datatypes of your table columns are different, if you line them up as Select * from tableA union select * from tableB... Then the column will line up incorrectly and give you unexpected results.

Comment: @SoulTrain   Yes that is the point.  This question is soliciting ideas on a workable structure.

Comment: You'd have to typecast everything to a compatible datatype; likely `VARCHAR`, but combining otherwise unrelated tables with different entities like this basically destroys data integrity by compromising the meaning of each field.  It's a relational nightmare, and the resulting view or table would be largely useless.  I'm struggling to understand why doing this would ever be a good idea.  It sounds like you're trying to resolve a display issue by ignoring the basic tenants of the relational model.

Comment: BaconBits   The current solution is to do exactly that - use a string (varchar) field.  The other obvious alternative is the suggestion from @jpw - to enumerate all fields and put nulls in the unused ones.  I put this out there to see if we were missing any other options since this is an important feature for us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a union query to do this, but you will have to specify every column for every table in the select statement; I don't know if I would call this a workable structure though - it's more a nightmare in my opinion and at least to me it's unclear what problem it's intended to solve...

```
select tname, common_key, taba_col1, taba_col2, tabb_col1, tabb_col2, tabb_col3,tabn_col1, tabn_col2, tabn_col3 
from (
    select 'TableA' as tname, common_key, taba_col1, taba_col2, null as tabb_col1, null as tabb_col2, null as tabb_col3,null as tabn_col1, null as tabn_col2, null as tabn_col3 from TableA
    union all
    select 'TableB' as tname, common_key, null, null, tabb_col1, tabb_col2, tabb_col3,null, null, null from TableB
    union all
    select 'TableC' as tname, common_key, null, null, null, null, null,tabn_col1, tabn_col2, tabn_col3 from TableN
) a
```

This would produce an output like:

```
tname   common_key  taba_col1   taba_col2   tabb_col1   tabb_col2   tabb_col3   tabn_col1   tabn_col2   tabn_col3
TableA  1           taba_col1   1           NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL
TableB  1           NULL        NULL        1,5         5,4         tabb_col3   NULL        NULL        NULL
TableC  1           NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        1           2015-01-01      2014-10-01
```

If you have a lot of tables and columns one way to handle this could be to build the query in a dynamic fashion using the information from the system catalog views.

Comment: Thanks, yes this is one of the two solutions we thought of (the other as mentioned by @baconbits to be stuffing all of the fields into a string/varchar and then manual parsing).  I will upvote as a reasonable idea yet wait for other ideas as well.